# How to use ODBC to connect to any DBMS

Tags: odbc

I'm developping a java application and i'm using JDBC to connect to MySQL Database, now i want to use ODBC to be able to get and retrieve data from any DBMS, of course if have access to it. Is there an API or tool to do this ?

Comment: In Java you use JDBC. ODBC is e.g. for C or Pascal programs. Why would you want to use ODBC if you are using Java? You can connect to any DBMS using JDBC just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a JDBC-ODBC bridge. There are several available. It is not recommended, instead you should always use a native JDBC driver.